# Jekyll and OSX 10.11 GM

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll, osx-elcapitan

I have updated to OSX 10.11 (GM) and have gone to work on some Jekyll projects. However when i try to serve the jekyll site i am getting the following error:-

```
-bash: jekyll: command not found
Alans-MacBook:new-site alan$
```

I have been looking around to see if there is a solution, but have yet to find one that can help.

I was wondering if anyone has also ran into this, and if there is a solution.

Comment: Can you please run `gem list` and paste the output? Did you install ruby using brew or do you have the default installation?

Comment: Hi @AlexPalcuie i worked out what the issue was. All my gems were installed and all appeared to be ok. It was simply cause xcode and the command line tools had not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i worked out what the actual issue was!

Apple has added System Integrity Protection (SIP) to increase security. This means that Jekyll has been effected as it uses the default Ruby install.
[More details on SIP](http://www.macworld.com/article/2948140/os-x/private-i-el-capitans-system-integrity-protection-will-shift-utilities-functions.html).

To get around this other users have been installing the Homebrew version. It's also likely that Jekyll v3.0 will start to move towards using this version too.

- Install the Xcode command line utilities:

  ```
  xcode-select --install
  ```
- Install Homebrew (instructions at http://brew.sh)
- Modify `$PATH` to use Homebrew:

  ```
  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Modify `$PATH` for GUI apps:

  ```
  launchctl setenv PATH "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
  ```
- Install the latest Ruby:

  ```
  brew install ruby
  ```
- Install the latest Jekyll:

  ```
  gem install jekyll
  ```